A kid who defeats bad guys using his toys
I'm looking for a movie. It's old. 
I don't remember much but there are bad guys in a house and there is a kid that uses his toys to defeat the bad guys. The kid takes a water gun and fills it up with gasoline or something like that and then he sneaks outside and there is a bad guy that lights his cigarette and the kid shoots and the bad guy goes up in flames. 
It's horror or thriller or action. It's not Home Alone or Remote. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Did the kid have some kind of a disability by any chance? And did he have a friend?

It might be anywhere from rugrats to little rascals, can you provide a little more detail like - was this kid alone and gender of the kid - does these events happen in a home or outside

The scene appears in Playing Dangerous, a Home Alone clone from 1995.

A young scientific whiz (Mikey LeBeau) virtually single-handedly defeats corporate mercernaries who take his family hostage to get a blueprint for a top secret super-fast computer chip.

You can see the water gun & cigarette scene in the trailer from 1:34 onwards:



